# Unrecognized options "sandbox, swagger" under "nelmio_api_doc". Available options are "areas", "documentation", "models"

Tags: swagger, symfony4, sandbox, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm trying to implement a Rest API for an application I develop using Symfony 4.
After installing packages such as : *nelmio/api-doc-bundle* (my composer.json is pasted bellow), I am getting the following error :

> *InvalidConfigurationException Unrecognized options "sandbox, swagger" under "nelmio_api_doc". Available options are "areas",
>   "documentation", "models".*.

I'm trying to figure out what is happening for days now.
Please need help.

This is my composer.json :

```
{
  "type": "project",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "cocur/slugify": "^3.2",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "^1.6",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.5",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
    "inacho/php-credit-card-validator": "^1.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^3.3",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.4",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.3",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/filesystem": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/finder": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
    "symfony/translation": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
    "zircote/swagger-php": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.2.*"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": {
      "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
      "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "allow-contrib": false,
      "require": "4.2.*"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my nelmio_api_doc.yaml

```
nelmio_api_doc:
  sandbox:
    enabled: true
    authentication:
      delivery: http
      type: bearer
    body_format:
      formats: [json, form] # array of enabled body formats,
      default_format: json
  swagger:
    api_base_path: /api
    swagger_version: "1.2"
    api_version: "0.1"
    info:
      title: API
      description: "REST API"
```

I tried: composer update and composer install.

Comment: You've got `nelmio_api_doc: sandbox: ...` and `nelmio_api_doc: swagger: ...` - The message clearly says these (`sandbox` and `swagger`) are unsupported. Have you read the [Symfony setup documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html) ? Examples there do not show what you've got...

Answer (score 0):

You must have updated `nelmio/api-doc-bundle` from 2.x to 3.x.

Your configuration seems good for a 2.x version.
Make sure to follow this [guide for migration to 3.x](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md).

For a similar issue which faced, I replaced `sandbox` with `documentation`.

Similarly, by following the guide, you can replace the rest.

Most likely something similar to the following will work.

```
nelmio_api_doc:
  documentation: #<-- notice this change.
    enabled: true
    authentication:
      delivery: http
      type: bearer
    body_format:
      formats: [json, form] # array of enabled body formats,
      default_format: json

    api_base_path: /api
    swagger_version: "1.2"
    info:
      title: API
      description: "REST API"
      version: "0.1" # <-- notice this has been moved.
```